# Split dataset into half, randomly selecting half of each level of chosen variable

Tags: r, random

I know how to split the dataset in half completely randomly no problem, but while I understand "logically" how to go about what I want to do, the twist here seems to be throwing me off.

So I have a dataset with a categorical variable `Title` which has 120 levels. Each level has 50 observations. I'd like to split the dataset in half in such a way where each of halfset A and halfset B get a random 25 of the 50 observations for each level of `Title`. (this is for EFA and CFA)

I think it would involve a for loop to loop through the 120 levels and `sample(nrow(subset(dataset,title=index), 25)`, but I'm a little lost beyond that. What little potential solutions I've thought of does the selecting a random 25 for halfset A but with replacement, so when I run it again to make halfset B, it has some overlap.

Example Data:

```
set.seed(1)
dataset = data.frame(id = rep(1:120, 50), v = rnorm(120*50))
```

Thanks as always, everyone.

Comment: While your description is good, it's best to also make a reproducible example with code, like `set.seed(1); DF = data.frame(id = rep(1:120, 50), v = rnorm(120*50))`

Answer (score 2):

I would `group_by` the data by title and then `sample` within each to get random ordering and use this to `split` the data.frame

```
#some data
df <- data.frame(title = letters[1:5], col = rnorm(30))

library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% group_by(title) %>% mutate(group = sample(n())/n() > 0.5)
split(df2, df2$group)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the caret package. The code below uses their instructions:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1); DF = data.frame(id = rep(1:120, 50), v = rnorm(120*50))
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(DF$id, p = .5,
                                  list = FALSE,
                                  times = 1)

DFTrain <- DF[ trainIndex,]
DFTest  <- DF[-trainIndex,]
table(DFTrain$id)
```

More about data splitting with the Caret package:
[Data Splitting](http://topepo.github.io/caret/splitting.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic split-apply-combine problem. Using the iris data:

```
x <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(iris,iris$Species), function(x) x[sample(round(nrow(x)/2)),]))
summary(x)
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width   
 Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100  
 1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:1.550   1st Qu.:0.300  
 Median :5.800   Median :3.000   Median :4.500   Median :1.400  
 Mean   :5.872   Mean   :3.061   Mean   :3.804   Mean   :1.212  
 3rd Qu.:6.450   3rd Qu.:3.350   3rd Qu.:5.100   3rd Qu.:1.800  
 Max.   :7.700   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500  
       Species  
 setosa    :25  
 versicolor:25  
 virginica :25
```

Or alternatively, you can select rows in the data frame by sampling the rows for each level in your splitting variable:

```
y <- iris[unlist(lapply(levels(iris$Species), function(x) sample(which(iris$Species==x),round(sum(iris$Species==x)/2)))),]
summary(y)
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width    Petal.Length    Petal.Width          Species  
 Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.00   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100   setosa    :25  
 1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:2.70   1st Qu.:1.500   1st Qu.:0.350   versicolor:25  
 Median :5.700   Median :3.00   Median :4.200   Median :1.300   virginica :25  
 Mean   :5.784   Mean   :3.02   Mean   :3.725   Mean   :1.204                  
 3rd Qu.:6.400   3rd Qu.:3.30   3rd Qu.:5.250   3rd Qu.:1.800                  
 Max.   :7.900   Max.   :4.40   Max.   :6.600   Max.   :2.500
```